# Standard error of absorved fixed effect // Run regression with noninteger factor variable

Tags: regression, stata

I have a regression that I can run for example as

```
reghdfe y, a(x1_est=x1 x2_est=x2)
```

which will store the estimated coefficients in `x1_est` and `x2_est`. Now, the issue is that using `absorb()` does not allow me to get the standard errors for these coefficients. If I understand it correctly, no postestimation method of `reghdfe` allows me to retrieve those.

Luckily, I only care about the standard errors of `x1`. So, I could instead run

```
reg y i.x1, a(x2)
```

and inspect `_se[x1]`. Unfortunately, `x1` has so many different levels that it is not possible to store it as integer, it has to be double. The previous regression hence will fail with `x1: factor variables may not contain noninteger values`.

What could be another approach to get standard errors for `x1`?

Comment: How many levels does x1 have? I think you're going past the limits of Stata here. In any case the maximum matsize is 11000, I don't think you can go beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

With large number of fixed effects, STATA's default approaches won't work. One angle is to bootstrap fixed effects and generate standard errors. Again, the issue is that there are so many FE, such that standard bootstrapping methods won't work (cannot return such a large matrix in each bootstrap).

Essentially, to bootstrap the FE, one would (for a large number of iterations)

- preserve
- bsample
- run the regression, `reghdfe y, a(x1_est=x1 x2_est-x2)`
- Store `x1_est` in a .dta file
- restore

After the loop is done, iteratively append all the .dta files, and compute standard errors.